# CodeIgniter and DataMapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I've read through a few different posts here and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My DB is setup like the following:

```
homes
- id
- address_id
- price
- etc...

address
- id
- home_id
- address1
- address2
- etc...
```

Then my models look like this, condensed.

```
home.php
<?php
class Home extends DataMapper {
    public var $has_one = array('address');
}

address.php
<?php
class Address extends DataMapper {
    public var $has_one = array('home');
}
```

Then my controller uses the following:

```
homes.php
class Homes extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('datamapper');
    }

    public function index() {
        $homes = new Homes();
        $homes->include_related('address');
        $homes->get_iterated();

        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

        _p($homes); // Self made function that wraps a print_r() in two <pre> tags.
}
}
```

If I comment out these two lines I get the standard CI return array.

```
$homes->include_related('address');
$homes->get_iterated();
```

If I don't then I get a server error. This is my first time using DataMapper and I'm almost certain I'm doing everything wrong, but have no idea where to start.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out my issue. I had to change the DB table `address` to `addresses` and in my `address.php` model I had to specify `var $table = 'addresses';`

That fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can specify the table name in your model. Also your example was wrong :

```
$homes = new Homes();
```

Should be

```
$homes = new Home();
```

I usually redefine the table name within my model to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: I realized this after some development. I'm still not able to get the results I'm after, but at this point I'm making the assumption my `$has_many` variable is the cause of this. I can get a single result, but a list of related results is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your relations is wrong. I assume you are setting a One to One relation ship. The doc say :
http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/relationtypes.html

> Because this is a One to One relationship, the relationship could have been stored in three ways:
>
> 1. As shown, on the workers table.
> 2. On the workplaces table, as worker_id
> 3. On a dedicated workers_workplaces join table, with the columns id, worker_id, and workplace_id

But here you have added *address_id* to **home** and *home_id* in **address**.
You have to choose between on. For example keep *home_id* in **address** and remove *address_id* in **home**.